# flutter - correct way to create a box that starts at minHeight, grows to maxHeight

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a container that I want to start off at a minimum size and grow (if its contents grow while user is adding content) to a maximum size, then stop.

The correct widget for this seems to be ConstrainedBox, like so:

```
new ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: new BoxConstraints(
    minHeight: 35.0,
    maxHeight: 60.0,
  ),
  child: ...child with growing content (has default height 25.0)...
),
```

however, this starts the box off at the maxHeight.

I tried to use hasBoundedHeight, but can not seem to construct the correct syntax for it or find an example in documentation.

What is the best way to get the box working as described?

Answer (score 242, accepted):

There's no notion of "Starts from max/min size".

The thing is, `ConstrainedBox` only add constraints to it's child. But in the end, it doesn't pick a size.

If you want your child to hit minSize, then they have to *not* expend. Which translate into *not* having a width/height of `double.INFINITY`. Fact is that `double.INFINITY` is the default value of many widgets, including `Container`.

On the other hand, some widgets such as `DecoratedBox` have a default size of 0.
Which means that this code :

```
return new ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: new BoxConstraints(
    minHeight: 5.0,
    minWidth: 5.0,
    maxHeight: 30.0,
    maxWidth: 30.0,
  ),
  child: new DecoratedBox(
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
  ),
);
```

Will render a 5.0*5.0 red square.

Comment: Ohhhhhh. So I need a new question, "how to listen and measure size of an object that starts at one size and ends up another"

Comment: You usually won't need this. Most widgets have an option to "fit the smalest size". For example, `ListView`/`GridView` have `shrinkWrap` property. `Row`/`Column` have `mainAxisSize` which can be set to `MainAxisSize.min`, ...

Comment: My real concern is when the object grows to max size in this case.

Comment: Yeah but you can combine this with a ConstrainedBox.

Comment: When the `ConstrainBox` is put in a `Container` it stops working. It follows the height set of the wrapping `Container`

Answer (score 43):

Below Example will help you to grow Size of the widget as required

```
Container(
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
              minHeight: 100, minWidth: double.infinity, maxHeight: 400),
          child: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: <Widget>[
              ...List.generate(
                10,  // Replace this with 1, 2 to see min height works. 
                (index) => Text(
                  'Sample Test: ${index}',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60, color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

**Output for Min Height for Single Item:**

[image]

**Output for Min Height for 10 Items:**

[image]

**Note:** This will show widgets as per mentioned max-height.

Comment: found `...List.generate` useful for combining array of elements and static elements inside a ListView, thanks

Answer (score 7):

Let me explain:

If child of `BoxConstraints` is (`Column` widget)  or (`ListView` widget), `maxHeight` will not work as expected, it will work as `height`, to solve that:

1 - If child of `BoxConstraints` is `Column`, your code need to be like this:

```
 Container(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(
      maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .30
    ),
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  
        children: const [
          // growable childrens
        ],
      ),
    ),
);
```

2- If child of `BoxConstraints` is `ListView`, your code need to be like this:

```
Container(
  constraints: BoxConstraints(
    maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .20,
  ),
  child: ListView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    children: const [
      // growable childrens
    ],
  ),
);
```

As is the case if child of `BoxConstraints` is `Row`, `maxWidth` will not work as expected, it will work as `width`, to solve that you need to set `mainAxisSize` to `MainAxisSize.min` like this:

```
 Container(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(
      maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .15
    ),
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  
        children: const [
          // growable childrens
        ],
      ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: 2- If child of BoxConstraints is ListView, your code need to be like this:

Answer (score 3):

You can use deviceWidth and deviceHeight to check for min and max condition.
Use the following code to get the deviceWidth and deviceHeight in build method.

```
double deviceWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
double deviceHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
```

In `width` and `height` property of `Container` use `deviceWidth` and `deviceHeight` to form your condition.

```
Container(
width: deviceWidth<200?50:deviceWidth*0.5,
height: deviceHeight<500?50:deviceHeight>800?200:deviceHeight*0.2,
child: //child,
)
```

Note: Only Ternary Operator `?:` works for specifying condition for height and width

Answer (score 3):

For `Column` for example, `minHeight` is not working. I solved it using this hack:

```dart
ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 150),
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      Column(
        children: [dynamicChild1, dynamicChild2],
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

So, just by wrapping `Column` in `Stack`. Now the Column size became 150 and more.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, ConstrainedBox is the right widget for the purpose.
If you'll give only minHeight parameter for eg. 300, the child will be of minimum height and will increase its size according to its content.

Here's an example:

```
ConstrainedBox(
   constraints: BoxConstraints(
       minHeight: 300,
       ),
   child: Container(child : SomeWidget(),)
```

If height required by SomeWidget() is less than 300, it will be of height 300. Otherwise, it will increase it's height accordingly.
For decoration and structuring your SomeWidget(), you can use padding and other properties of Container.

Answer (score 1):

As Remi's answer points out, if your `ConstrainedBox` is initially maxing out a dimension when you expected it to be closer to or at the min, it's because a child wants to be big. (Re: [Constraints go down. Sizes go up. Parent sets position.](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints)) If you aren't sure which child is causing it, one handy way is to use the Widget Inspector in your IDE and check the properties of the descendants, then check the docs as to why and adjust accordingly.

For example, I've run into this e.g. when wrapping a widget in `Center`. Normally without constraints the centered widget would match the child's height. However, when putting the `Center` inside a `ConstrainedBox`, all of a sudden it blew up to the max constraints. After checking the docs, I saw that:

1. `This widget will be as big as possible if its dimensions are constrained and widthFactor and heightFactor are null`, explaining the new layout.
2. But: `If a dimension is unconstrained and the corresponding size factor is null then the widget will match its child's size in that dimension`, which explains the behavior without the
   `ConstrainedBox`.
3. And this tells me how to fix it:  `If a size factor is non-null then the corresponding dimension of this widget will be the product of the child's dimension and the size factor`,
   i.e. set the `Center`'s `heightFactor: 1`.

So pay attention to how your children behave! If you impose external constraints, they may be greedy (or not, just like real kids ;).

Answer (score 0):

try to use Contraints box instead of Sized box because sized box have not min height and min width property they just have height and width property

```
 ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: const BoxConstraints(
        maxHeight: Dimension.d9,
        minHeight: Dimension.d9,
        maxWidth: 144.0
      ),
    );
```