# BoxConstraints maxHeight is always applied when set

Tags: flutter, flutter-container

I have a container in which I have set the below constraints value

```
constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 300),
```

In the container widget, It has a child whose height is set to 200 but when the app is run the height is set to 300 instead of 200.

How to solve this?

Comment: Can you paste complete sample code here with parent container and child container?

Comment: This could be because the Container widget tries to big as possible. Please post the complete sample.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answers here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48676681/12838877

You have to set the `minHeight` or `minWidth`, to override the default value.
just applied to my code and works as expected.

```
ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: new BoxConstraints(
    minHeight: 5.0,
    minWidth: 5.0,
    maxHeight: 30.0,
    maxWidth: 30.0,
  ),
  child: new DecoratedBox(
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
  ),
)
```